# Is there a good free doc-to-chm converter out there?

Tags: converters, chm

I am looking for a converter .doc to .chm. I find lots but with most you need to buy to be able to convert a whole document. 
ANyone knows of a good converter without needing to buy it?

THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your document to .html using a suitable WORD version.

Then use the free ms help workshop to archive the html to a .chm. You might need to do some work here to build a TOC and index.

There might be tools that try to recover the TOC from Word outlines though. I've no experience with them.

Comment: Seems that ms help workshop has a way to convert <Hx> HTML outlines to TOCs. (auto toc/auto index)